# LINQ way to check if a list contains an object from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of objects and I want to check if a different List contains a certain object. I have written some code that works for it I just couldn't quite figure out a way to do it with LINQ (if possible)

```
                        foreach (var file in files)
                        {
                            if (!pushedList.Contains(file))
                            {
                                myStack.Push(file);
                                pushedList.Add(file);
                            }
                        }
```

Something like  `if (!pushedList.Contains(files.Select(f => f)))` except I just want to select the 1 file that is inside of files. The two List's in question are files and pushedList

Comment: You question isn't clear to me. That said, maybe this is what you are looking for, `var results = files.Where(a => !pushedList.Any(b => b.Contains(a))).ToList();`. This will populate `results` with items from `files` that are not in `pushedList`.

Comment: If the lists are large, consider whether you can use a `HashSet` instead. With lists, the operation is O(M*N) whereas with a hash set, it is O(N). Foreach is a linear iteration and so is Contains() on a list.

Comment: @quaabaam Your code doesn't make sense: you are testing if a file `b` contains another file `a` (better naming wouldn't hurt).

Comment: So you're after the intersection of the two lists, i.e. the set of objects that are in both lists? Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LINQ is for querying and not modifying, you just use it to figure out the files you need to process, then do the processing on those files:

```
var missingFiles = files.Where(f => !pushedList.Contains(f)).ToList();
myStack.PushRange(missingFiles);
pushedList.AddRange(missingFiles);
```

Depending on the sizes, it may be worthwhile to make a `HashSet` from `pushedList` before doing the query, or ideally, make `pushedList` a `HashSet` instead of a `List`.

This uses an extension to `Stack<T>`:

```
public static class StackExt {
    public static void PushRange<T>(this Stack<T> s, IEnumerable<T> Ts) {
        foreach (var t in Ts)
            s.Push(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close! Thank you, the only issue is stack doesn't have a PushRange method so it pushes all of the missingFiles onto the stack instead of 1 at a time :). Also thank you for the suggestion! Theoretically, what this is designed for the files shouldn't be more than about 1000 but I definitely need to improve its efficiency

Comment: @mharre I'm sorry, that was my fault, it is a standard extension I have. I added the definition to the answer.

Comment: No worries It was a simple fix :)

Comment: @mharre I try to remember to turn off my (extensive) `My Extensions` when testing in LINQPad, but sometimes I forget...